# Mongo filter 'in' vs. linq version

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

What would be more efficient between:

using the *in* filter:

```
var filter = Builders<Employee>.Filter.In(x => x._id, IdList);
```

or, using linq and pass the following expression:

```
(x => IdList.Contains(x))
```

Is the MongoDB driver able to decompose both the same way?

Comment: This calls for the Speed Rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ You can skip "Part the first".

Comment: @Christopher, we're talking about a small data set, so the answer is irrelevant in term of absolute results. It's more about me wanting to know how things work under the hood for future cases. Maybe the answer is that LINQ queries are decomposed into the mongo filter primitives, or that a large amount of data is retrieved in a very big list processed through linq... I don't know, but I'd like to know :)

Comment: Not a bad idea. It is a standing advice I give: If you have to do filtering, you should always do it in the DB request. Retrieving too much just to do filtering in the client will only cause issues. But personally I would always just do explicit filtering in the Query, rather then hoping for LINQ to be turned into proper DB orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i guess it depends on which endpoint you use with the filter or linq query. for ex:

```cs
collection.Find(Builders<Employee>.Filter.In(x => x.ID, IdList))
collection.Find(x => IdList.Contains(x.ID))
```

both translates to:

```java
db.Employees.find({
    "_id": {
        "$in": [
            ObjectId("5d462fbd548a6107ccb019b6"),
            ObjectId("5d462fbd548a6107ccb019b7")
        ]
    }
})
```

and

```cs
collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => IdList.Contains(x.ID))
collection.Aggregate().Match(x => IdList.Contains(x.ID))
```

both translates to:

```java
db.Employees.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": {
                "_id": {
                    "$in": [
                        ObjectId("5d462fbd548a6107ccb019b6"),
                        ObjectId("5d462fbd548a6107ccb019b7")
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

so i think the fair comparison would be "find" vs. "aggregation" instead of "filter" vs. "linq" if query performance is your concern.

afaik, the main difference between find and aggregation is they (might) use different query plans and indexes. not exactly sure... [you be the judge](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+find+vs+aggregation)...